# How to increment Dataframe row name value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this dataframe:

```
              OP1    OP2       OP3       OP4        OP5        OP6        OP7        OP8        OP9       OP10       Total
Simulation1   NaN    0.0    471294.2  692828.5  1107766.9  1580052.7  2452123.5  4374088.4  4545222.2  4764249.9  19987626.3 


              OP1    OP2       OP3       OP4       OP5        OP6        OP7        OP8        OP9       OP10       Total
Simulation1   NaN    0.0    333833.4  573533.5  948961.2  1343783.2  2354595.9  4061858.2  4348907.9  4769410.1  18734883.4 


              OP1    OP2       OP3       OP4       OP5        OP6        OP7        OP8        OP9       OP10       Total
Simulation1   NaN    0.0     441838.4  660710.6  976074.4  1391775.4  2002799.8  3921497.8  3708159.7  3852268.8  16955124.9
```

I need this row name as like this :

```
   OP1    OP2       OP3       OP4        OP5        OP6        OP7        OP8          OP9         OP10          Total

Simulation1   NaN    0.0    471294.2  692828.5  1107766.9  1580052.7   2452123.5   4374088.4   4545222.2    4764249.9     19987626.3 

Simulation2   NaN    0.0    333833.4  573533.5  948961.2   1343783.2   2354595.9   4061858.2   4348907.9    4769410.1     18734883.4 

Simulation3   NaN    0.0    441838.4  660710.6  976074.4   1391775.4   2002799.8   3921497.8   3708159.7    3852268.8     16955124.9
```

.
.
.
So on

Here I have to increment row name simulation1 ,simulation2...so on

I have this code:

```
 simulationDf=pd.DataFrame(columns['OP1','OP2','OP3','OP4','OP5','OP6','OP7','OP8','OP9','OP10','Total'])
 simulationDf.loc['Simulation1'] = ultiCalc['Reserves']
```

Comment: Is the top box ONE dataframe, or THREE dataframes each with one row? Hard to guess what your data generating process is from what is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that is your index(the dataframe that you posted in second code block) so you can use `.index` attribute and list comprehension:

```
df.index=['Simulation'+str(x) for x in range (1,len(df)+1)]
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
              OP1    OP2       OP3       OP4        OP5        OP6        OP7        OP8          OP9         OP10          Total

Simulation1   NaN    0.0    471294.2  692828.5  1107766.9  1580052.7   2452123.5   4374088.4   4545222.2    4764249.9     19987626.3 

Simulation2   NaN    0.0    333833.4  573533.5  948961.2   1343783.2   2354595.9   4061858.2   4348907.9    4769410.1     18734883.4 

Simulation3   NaN    0.0    441838.4  660710.6  976074.4   1391775.4   2002799.8   3921497.8   3708159.7    3852268.8     16955124.9
```